# Searching for Files on Win XP

Tags: windows, search

Yeah, I know I should upgrade but I'm going to be on XP for a bit longer.

When I do a [Start][Search][For Files or Folders], the Search Results window comes up where it asks me what kind of files I'm searching for (Pictures/Movies/Videos, Documents, etc).  My answer is *always* 'All Files and Folders'.  When I click that it takes me to the search criteria part.  I want to change the behavior (or add a shortcut to my desktop) that will skip the part where I have to specify 'All Files and Folders'.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I have no intention of leaving XP.

Comment: +1 for always answer "All Files and Folders" its amazing that they "hide" the best option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to continue using the built in search, but skip straight to the search for section, then go to Change Preferences

[image: change preferences]

--> Change Files and Folders Search Behavior

[image: change files and folders search behavior]

--> Advanced

[image: Advanced]

And hit OK.  This will take you straight to the boxes that lets you type in what to search for, where to search, and give you the ability to pick other options.

Comment: (a couple of screen shots would make it excellent ;-)

Comment: I'd include screenshots, but can't from the office.  sorry.

Comment: This has been one of my pet peeves for years! Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: @fretje - I can't edit yet (not enough rep) but here are the walkthrough images: http://bit.ly/cXQhVF  http://bit.ly/bHL9DA  http://bit.ly/bEZb8B

Answer (score 4):

Use voidtool's **[Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/)** instead

Features:

> Small installation file
>
> Clean and simple user interface
>
> Quick file indexing   Quick searching
>
> Minimal resource usage
>
> Share files with others easily
>
> Real-time updating

[image]

Windows desktop search doesn't get any better!

*Everything is freeware, a portable version is also available.*

Comment: +1 Everything is the best! You should note though that it only supports ntfs...

Comment: http://www.voidtools.com/faq.php#What_are_the_system_requirements_for__Everything

Comment: +1 Everything is the best search tool hands down!! Got this tip from one of Molly's posts a while back.

Answer (score 2):

Agent Ransack is the best. I do not like programs that build an index of all the files on my drives (like Everything and Google Desktop) because I have several private files on crypted drives which I do not want to result in any list.

Comment: so? Everything has an option 'Exclude', guess what it does? :)

Comment: Find and Run Robot is fantastic software. Super fast and super customisable. Was a life saver back in my XP days. http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/findrun/

Answer (score 0):

You might get better control of your search by using [Windows Search](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/default.mspx) or [Google Desktop](http://desktop.google.com/). Generally these index the files that you're speaking about and give back faster results than the built-in search features of XP.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice to get voted down, but how is Everything any different from Windows Search and Google Desktop in that it still creates an index of files and folders?

Comment: Everything only searches in file *names* (which was what the OP asked), not in file *contents*, so it's much faster to build its index. It's also a very lightweight application which can't be said from any of Windows Search or Google Desktop. (I *didn't* downvote you, btw)